# Regular expression logic

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, components

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I have a question:
I'm creating a custom input component (for text input) such as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-text',
  templateUrl: './input-text.component.html'
  ]
})
export class InputTextComponent {

  @Input() pattern?: string;

}
```

I would like a user can insert a **regular expression** for the validation of the input field, in this way:

```
<input-text pattern="^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$"></input-text>
```

The **template of my component** is defined like this:

```
<input type="text" [attr.pattern]="pattern"/>
```

Unfortunately I know absolutely nothing about regular expressions. 
I would like to do two things:

1 - Create a method that checks the validity of the regular expression and changes the visual style.

2 - Make sure that if the input (with a `pattern` field) is inserted into a form, the attribute `form.valid` remains false until the expression is valid.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check regex validity

You can simply catch exceptions thrown by the RegExp constructor when instanciating it.

```
try {
  const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
} catch (error) {
  // If it goes here, then the regex model is not correct
  console.error(error.message)
}
```

2. Change the visual style

You can simply use the ngClass attribute to change your input style.
If you enter the `catch` statement, set a style variable to change the class like so

```
private hasBadInput: boolean;
// [...]
catch (error) {
  hasBadInput= true;
}
```

Then apply a specific class in that case:

```
<input-text [ngClass]="{'yourErrorClass': hasBadInput}"><input-text>
```

3. Form validity

You did well using `[attr.pattern]`, the form should automatically consider the entered pattern. You should try your form with a hard written regex before, and then use the input one.
Follow this [official guideline](https://angular.io/guide/forms) to create Angular 2+ forms.

Comment: Thanks! I have a question: in the first code (try-catch), 
nothing is happening. 
How do I compare a string with a regular expression?

Comment: If you don't have any errors into your Regex, nothing will happen specifically. Try something like '//(', you should have an exception rising and go to the catch.
For more about RegExp object, please refer to the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp